# Android: How to access variables from BroadcastReceiver in Activity?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a class **Connect** which takes a reference an Activity to access the UI.thread. Inside of it I have this broadcast:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(split);
Log.i(TAG, "JSON Array: " + json.toString());
String[] userNames = new String[json.length()];
for(int user = 0; user < json.length(); user++)
{
  userNames[user] = json.getString(user);
}
Intent mainIntent = new Intent();
mainIntent.putExtra("OnlineUsers", userNames);
mainIntent.setAction("com.app.SEND_DATA");
activity.sendBroadcast(mainIntent);
```

in my **MainActivity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      // Extract data included in the Intent
      String[] usersNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("OnlineUsers");
      Log.i(TAG, "Got message: " + Arrays.toString(usersNames));
    }
};
```

I register the broadcast in **onCreate()** inside **MainActivity**:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.app.SEND_DATA");
registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
```

How now to access the **userNames** inside my **onCreate** method or do you think there is a better way of passing variables to the activity when my **Connect** class takes a **reference** of that Activity ?

Comment: try using interface overridden method in your activity class.

Answer (score 2):

use Handler and Messege.

here sample :

Handler mhandle;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mhandle = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            String[] user_name = (String[])msg.obj;
            //some code//
        }
    };
    //and registerReceiver//
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.app.SEND_DATA");
    registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
}
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String[] usersNames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("OnlineUsers");
        Log.i(TAG, "Got message: " + Arrays.toString(usersNames));
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = usersNames;
        mhandle.sendMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

i hope work.

Comment: oh. and super.handleMessage(msg); it is nothing. you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access to the usersNames variable in your onCreate(). And it will be fool to do that because your userNames will be undefined or null if it's correct.

If you want to change TextView or EditText or whatever, do it in the onReceive().